# How to enable store virtual directory and Store controller in MVC4 application in Windows 2003 server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, asp.net-mvc-routing

ASP.NET MVC4 applicaton in Windows 2003 server using IIS is in virtual directory store and has Store controller, e.q url can be

```
http://mysite.com/store/Store/Details?product=C201S
```

This application need to be accessed from root also, as

```
http://mysite.com/Store/Details?product=C201S
```

For this copy of application directory has created and default web application is pointed to it.
However http://mysite.com/Store/Details?product=C201S returns error

```
The resource cannot be found. 
  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

 Requested URL: /Store/Details


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

Links which toes not contail Store controller in url work OK.
It looks like store application and Store controller name collision. How to fix this ?

global.asax.cs contains default rounting:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    //http://haacked.com/archive/2010/02/12/asp-net-mvc-2-optional-url-parameters.aspx
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

Comment: By setup an virtual directory and placing a web application in there the root of your web application is the virtual directory: `http://my site.com/VIRTUAL_DIRECTORY/`. So there is no collision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my comment, to make both Url's work you should set the home directory of the virtual directory's parent web site to the same directory like the virtual directory [this page](http://www.serverintellect.com/support/iis/alt-home-dir/) shows you how to do it.

Comment: Home directory of root in default web site is set to c:\myapp\web\storepea and home direcotry of store virtual directory is set to c:\myapp\web\store in virtual directory properties. What should exactly changed? I updated question and added image

Comment: @Andrus The home directory of your default website should be changed to `c:\myapp\web\store`.